# Report Multiple IPs to tracker rtorrent

Tags: ip, rtorrent

There is an option in rtorrent to report an IP to the tracker.

I have a seeding rtorrent box connected to 4 WAN connections.

I have configured port forwarding on all 4 wan connections and also made sure it is working.

Now can i configure .rtorrent.rc file to report the tracker the IP's of all 4 WAN connections so that the peers can connect me via all lines ?

I am doing this via an external load balancing and it doesn't support next hopping.

I tried putting multiple 'IP' entries in the .rtorrent.rc file but rtorrent seems to read the last IP in that list.. perhaps overwriting the variable as it reads the file from top ..

Any advice ..

Thanks.